# Android, rotate bitmap around self center without scale it

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-canvas, android-bitmap

When I rotate a bitmap around it, size of bitmap image changed and rotation show with a shake.

```
public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, int width, float angle) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        int px = width / 2;
        matrix.postRotate(angle, px, px);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, width, width, matrix, true);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

With each call for draw it in canvas, some added to bitmap's width and height and rotate with shaking.
how to rotate smoothly without shake bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

It is resizing because you're passing a half width of it. Use this:

```
public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    return bitmap;
}
```

As for shaking, you must call it on another thread. (`AsyncTask`, etc)